# In-App Purchase Product Request Method Needs Two Calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, request, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I currently have created a series of methods that call and return In-App Purchase products that I have created. I can call the `SKProductRequest` without issue, I can even purchase the item and receive a successful purchase notification (`SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`).

The **issue** is that for whatever reason, when I initially run the app, I have to call the following methods 2 times in order to receive a **non-null** response from Apple:

```
/// In app purchases

- (IBAction)BuyProduct:(id)sender {
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:_productID]];
        request.delegate = self;

        [request start];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Please enable In App Purchasing in your settings");
    }
}


#pragma mark _
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSArray *products = response.products;

    if (products.count != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Products available: %@", _product.localizedTitle);
        _product = products[0];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Products not found.");
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products) {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }
}
```

Every time, the first time I call the BuyProduct `IBAction` i receive this:
(excuse the dashes - simply clearing my personal info!)

```
---------- --.07.55.823 -------[2474:827710] Products available: (null)
```

Then the **second** time and onwards that I call the same `IBAction` button, I receive the IAP name correctly,

```
---------- --.08.03.142 -------[2474:827710] Products available: TEST IAP
---------- --.08.04.455 -------[2474:827710] Products available: TEST IAP
```

**SO**, I am just trying to figure out why I need to call these methods 2 times in order for Apple (or my code) to successfully return my IAP product name. If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @ Will Von Did you got any solution to your problem? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Yes. NSLog(@"Products available: %@", _product.localizedTitle); _product = products[0]; This was the issue. I was simply showing (null), nothing, before I was able to grab the product available. I had to simply display the localizedTitle AFTER I obtained the product. Silly mistake but at first look slightly alarming